# UIImageView set image programmatically bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uistoryboard

I have a UIImageView in a storyboard, connected to the header of the subclassed UIViewController like this:
`@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *displayPhoto;`

In the `.m` of the UIViewController subclass, I try to set the image of the `displayPhoto`.

```
@synthesize displayPhoto;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dp.jpg"];

    [displayPhoto setImage:image];

    displayPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = displayPhoto.image.size.width/2;

    [self.view addSubview:displayPhoto];
}
```

but it does absolutely nothing. If I add one more line, adding another view of the image like so: `[self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];`, making my methodf

```
@synthesize displayPhoto;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dp.jpg"];

    [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];

    [displayPhoto setImage:image];

    displayPhoto.layer.cornerRadius = displayPhoto.image.size.width/2;

    [self.view addSubview:displayPhoto];
}
```

It suddenly starts working and adds to instances of the image to the view. One in the top left corner (from the line I added) and a second in the storyboard image location.

What's changing? How is adding that one line making my code work and is there any work around so I can make the image just show up as normal?

Comment: key question: is displayPhoto null if you set a breakpoint in the debugger and inspect? Is it possible that you didn't connect the UImageView in Interface Builder to your IBOutlet property?

Comment: Maybe awakeFromNib is too early. Try to move your code in awakeFromNib to viewDidLoad and see if it works. I suppose your IBOutlet is connected properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added the UIImage in your storyboard and connected the outlet correctly, there is no need to create a new image programmatically. Try this.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.displayPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dp.jpg"];
}
```

Comment: Its still not working... I have the `@property` like so: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *displayPhoto;` and I added the viewDidLoad exactly as you did, I even added a NSLog to make sure the `viewDidLoad` ran. It did, but theres still no image in the imageView showing up

Comment: @user3451350 Use your assistant editor with your header file and your storyboard. Make sure the circle is filled and when you mouse over it and the correct image in your storyboard is highlighted. You can also remove the awakeFromNib code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the connection of imageview to storyboard will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
self.imgObj.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your string"];
```